# How to create JWT exp style date in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth-2.0, jwt

I'll like to create JWT exp claim style date in Javascript. My app jwt claim returns an expiry date of 1424984529. I'm doing a test for token expiration using this:

```
if(jwt.exp < Date.now())) {
  // do something
}
```

As at writing Date.now() gives me 1424941329632 and jwt.exp gives 1424984529. Obviously, my test will always return true.

So my question is, how do I mimic jwt-style exp date in Javascript?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

How about:

```
if (jwt.exp < Date.now() / 1000) {
  // do something
}
```